# How to avoid copying HTML & CSS contents in Inline Edit using contenteditable Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In Inline Edit we are trying to copy-paste own content but it copies html content itself.

Please find the screen shot below:

[image]

How to avoid copying of the html content and styles?

We need to copy-paste only content itself.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cAHz7/650/)

**HTMl:**

```
<td><a href="" contentEditable="true" ng-model="fName">John</a></td>
```

**Angular :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            // view -> model
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.text());
                });
            });

            // model -> view
            ctrl.render = function(value) {
                elm.html(value);
            };

            // load init value from DOM
            ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.text());

            elm.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                console.log("keydown " + event.which);
                var esc = event.which == 27,
                    el = event.target;

                if (esc) {
                        console.log("esc");
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.text());
                        el.blur();
                        event.preventDefault();                        
                    }

            });

        }
    };
})
```

;

**CSS:**

```
a[contentEditable] {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
    padding: .2em;
}
a[contentEditable]:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
    border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .2em;
}
```

Comment: could you replicate the same on plnkr,http://.plnkr.io

Comment: @dreamweiver : 1 min i'll do in plunkr

Comment: @dreamweiver : https://plnkr.co/edit/3bL5KUjC0kJGRQdYWZ9z?p=preview

Comment: Could you please mention in which browser are you testing? I had a look at at Chrome 49 and only content is being copied and not its html markup.

Comment: @GibboK : All the browser look like same output for me (Chrome ,IE ,Firefox).just click the content copied and pasted in the end of the content.

Answer (score 0):

As option you can try to do:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function (e) {
   var pastedText = undefined;
   if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
     pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
   } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
     pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
   }
   // @see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand
   document.execCommand('inserttext', false, pastedText);
   return false; // Prevent the default handler from running.
});
```